# Detect git changes in web app?

Tags: php, git

I am wondering how services like Laravel Forge, and similar types of services automatically detect code changes.

- Do they check out a bare repo and keep running git fetch until they get new commits?
- Do they run `git remote update` over and over again?

It seems like running `git remote update` or something like that every 15 seconds would be the only way to do this? Am I missing something.

Comment: It's not an answer, but you can set up your git to notify other services on certain actions by creating a hook. In this case, Github (or whomever your host is) would define an `update` hook, which runs when receiving a `push`.

Comment: Yah, but a lot of these services (such as Laravel Forge) don't seem to require this, they seem to automatically check... And I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: One option might just be to do a SHA over all refs and track whether that changes, although that might miss orphaned objects (not sure if you are alerted to them changing) or maybe also git notes. OTOH, there might just be an overall SHA on the whole repo that could be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `git fetch` in a loop is a common way to achieve this. `.git/FETCH_HEAD` can then be examined to find out what was fetched.